# How can I set in VS Code the PYTHONPATH per project?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

I installed different python version from source, and created virtual environment for them, and Iset them in settings per project..
The OS (SuSe Leap) is coming with python 3.6.

How can I set in VS Code the PYTHONPATH per project ? , I don't want to modify the general path.

With the virtual environment set in settings work with python builtins, but doesn't look for third-party packages in the correct path.

I already have set `pythonPath` to the interpreter in the python environment, but I still have some issues with packages import, and I don't find a variable for PYTHONPATH ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have three methods to configure `PYTHONPATH`:

1.`terminal.integrated.env.*` in the `settings.json` file. For example:

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
  }
```

But it only affects the actions routed through the terminal such as debugging.

> When the terminal settings are used, PYTHONPATH affects any tools that
> are run within the terminal by a user, as well as any action the
> extension performs for a user that is routed through the terminal such
> as debugging. However, in this case when the extension is performing
> an action that isn't routed through the terminal, such as the use of a
> linter or formatter, then this setting will not have an effect on
> module look-up.

2.Configure `PYTHONPATH` in `.env` file:

> By default, the Python extension looks for and loads a file named .env
> in the current workspace folder. The file is identified by the default
> entry "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env" in your user
> settings.

But it will not affect the actions run in the terminal.

> When PYTHONPATH is set using an .env file, it will affect anything the
> extension does on your behalf and actions performed by the debugger,
> but it will not affect tools run in the terminal.

3.Configure the `"env"` entry in the `launch.json` file, such as:

```
{
  "name": "Python: Current File",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${file}",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
  }
}
```

Obviously, It only affects the debugging actions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit your settings.json for each project

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Additional info

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference

Comment: I already have the environment set but I don't find in docs a specific variable for PYTHONPATH, where to search/set thord-party packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set PYTHONPATH in .venv/bin/activate

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/your_home/your_user/project_root"
```

Answer (score 1):

To add extra hint paths for non-debugging purposes, for example to search for imports in a non-standard location, you can set it in `settings.json` using

```
{
    ...
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./build"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Now reload your VS Code window and imports and autocomplete will work fine!